# Best practice architecture, for multiple websites with commonality

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

We are looking to build multiple custom websites for different customer contracts, with tailored functionality, but all around the same theme and concept.

There will be about 70% commonality in functionality across all websites, but enough difference that building a CMS is a bad choice. Also customers dont want their DB to have properties that are not relevant to them.

The DB tables will be mostly the same, with a few different properties in each table per site. ie a customer table might be 80% the same, but in one project in might also ask for hair-color, eye-color, etc. whereas in another in might also ask for height and weight....

I'm ok with my other layers, but what is the best practise for the MVC presentation layer?
I want to create as many inherited functions/controllers/actions/resx/etc as possible via base classes (which will be the same project referenced by each website), but MVC does not seem to lend itself as well to this as webforms.

Any thoughts would be really appreciated, thanks

Comment: Do you have the custom properties defined in the database as an EAV (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model), or are they bolted on to the base table as additional columns?

Answer (score 0):

I would focus my efforts on the web config and building my presentation layer around config settings stored at server side. Also, I'm not entirely sure how logically different your pages will be, but having different CSS styles can dramatically change the look of your websites. This post was kinda vague, I hope I helped spurn some ideas...